# I can't get birthday with FACEBOOK SDK V4

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am unable to get birthday with my facebook sdk v4. Here are the details.

```
/* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

/* USE NAMESPACES */

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;

/*PROCESS*/

    //1.Stat Session
     session_start();

    //check if users wants to logout
     if($_REQUEST['logout']==1){
        unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
     }

    //2.Use app id,secret and redirect url 
    $app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    $app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $redirect_url='http://someurl.co//';

    //3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
     FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
     $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
     $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

    //check if facebook session exists
    if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])){
        $sess = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
    }

    //logout
    $logout = 'http://dryvr.co/fb/?logout=1';

    //4. if fb sess exists echo name 
        if(isset($sess)){
            //store the token in the php session
            $_SESSION['fb_token']=$sess->getToken();
            //create request object,execute and capture response
            $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me?fields=id,name,email,birthday');
            // from response get graph object
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
            // use graph object methods to get user details
            $name = $graph->getName();
            $id = $graph->getId();
            $birthday = $graph->getBirthday();
            $image = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/picture?width=300';
            $email = $graph->getProperty('email');
            $birthday = $graph->getProperty('birthday');
            echo "hi $name <br>";
            echo "your email is $email <br>";
            echo "your birthday is on $birthday <br>";
            echo "<a href='".$logout."'><button>Logout</button></a>";
        }else{
            //else echo login
            echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl(array('email')).'" >Login with facebook</a>';
        }
```

Also in graphUser.php, I have this function

```
public function getBirthday()
  {
    $value = $this->getProperty('birthday');
    if ($value) {
      return new \DateTime($value);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I have tried both, `$graph->getBirthday()` as well as `$graph->getProperty('birthday')` but i cant seem to echo it. How will I get the birthday? I am using `$birthday` variable. I am echoing it but it is blank. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tobi I can't get the birthday. What should I do? I have read that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the same question you posted yesterday, now with the `birthday` instead of `email`. If you don't specify the appropriate permission (`user_birthday`) in the login scope from `getLoginUrl()`, you'll never be able to get the data.

Please read the according docs, it's all there!

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0#login

Comment: pff. This was so annoying. Thankyou. It's done. I'm new to this api thing. So i'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Understandable, but please refer to the docs first before posting a question... Thanks.

Comment: I will. Thankyou and cheers.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help